# Why is the check "x not in y" not working?

Tags: python

I have written up a Tic Tac Toe game however there seems to be an error.
None of the players have won, nor there still exists `"-"` in `board`, the game just ends to a draw after some playing.
(Please see in `def check():` last `elif` statement.)

Could you please help me what is wrong with the code?
(Sorry I am a beginner and please excuse the lack of my code)

Here is my code below:

```
import sys

board = [["-","-","-"],["-","-","-"],["-","-","-"]]

def print_board():
    for x in board:
        print(" ".join(x))

P1X = input("Hi Player 1. What is your name? ")
P2O = input("Hi Player 2. What is your name? ")

def play_again():
    answer = input("It is a draw!. Do you want to play again? Y/N ").upper()
    if answer == "Y":
        play_game()
    else:
        sys.exit()

def check():
    if board[0][0] == board[0][1] == board[0][2]:
        check_win(0, 0)
    elif board[0][0] == board[1][0] == board[2][0]:
        check_win(0, 0)
    elif board[0][0] == board[1][1] == board[2][2]:
        check_win(0, 0)
    elif board[0][1] == board[1][1] == board[2][1]:
        check_win(1, 1)
    elif board[0][2] == board[1][2] == board[2][2]:
        check_win(2, 2)
    elif board[1][0] == board[1][1] == board[1][2]:
        check_win(1, 1)
    elif board[2][0] == board[2][1] == board[2][2]:
        check_win(2, 2)
    elif board[0][2] == board[1][1] == board[2][0]:
        check_win(1, 1)
    elif "-" not in board:
        print("It is a draw!")
        play_again()
    else:
        pass

def check_win(row,col):
    if board[row][col] == 'X':
        print_board()
        print("{0} has won the game. Game Over!".format(P1X))
        play_again()
    elif board[row][col] == "O":
        print_board()
        print("{0} has won the game. Game Over!".format(P2O))
        play_again()
    else:
        pass

count = 0

def place(row, col):
    if count == 0:
        board[row][col] = "X"
    else:
        board[row][col] = "O"

def play_game():
    global count
    print("Please start the game {0}".format(P1X))
    while count != 892:
        row_input = int(input("Please select the row ")) -1
        col_input = int(input("Please select the column ")) -1

        place(row_input, col_input)

        check()

        print_board()

        if count == 0:
            count = 1
            print("It is now {0}'s turn".format(P2O))
        else:
            count = 0
            print("It is now {0}'s turn".format(P1X))

play_game()
```

Comment: `board` is a _list of lists_, and clearly, `"-"` is not there, it's inside one of the inner lists.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment. I have tried with `"-" not in (board[0] and board[1] and board[2])` as an alternative but it had the same issue...

Comment: `board` contains rows. You want to check for presence of `"-"` in either of these rows. That `stuff in (a and b and c)` is one of the most common (and really surprising) beginner mistakes. You have to repeat that `stuff in something` clause three times and 'join' them with `and`s.

Comment: Oh that is why! Thank you very much for your explanative comment ForceBru! Your comment solved my mystery :)

Answer (score 1):

Your program doesn't define `check_win`, so I am not sure how it works at all. Your problem, however, is that you use a list of rows as your board representation, presumably starting with each board element as `'-'` to indicate unplayed spaces.

Depending on the rest of your code you might find it easier to use a dictionary as the board representation, with two-element tuples as subscripts.

As the code is now that last test would need to be modified to test that no row contains a `'-'`, which you could do with the test:

```
if not any('-' in row for row in board):
```

At present you are comparing lists with strings. That's never going to give you equality.

Comment: Havn't I defined `check_win` below function `check`? Thank you very much for your answer I will try that now! <3

Comment: Yes, you did - I simply failed to notice the scroll bar on the source! Glad it worked out.